# Multivariate Orthogonal Projections:

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, orthogonality, projective-space, projection

Suppose I want to Project the function $f(x,y)$ onto the function $g(x,y)$ (both defined on $R_+$). Can it be done by it be done by the following:
$$Proj_f \rightarrow g = \frac{<f,g>}{<g,g>} \times g $$
, where $<f,g> = \int \int_{R_+} f.g dx dy$

Comment: Yes, that's the unique orthogonal projection, where orthogonal is defined through your inner product. There are other types of projections that are not orthogonal. And orthogonality depends on the chosen inner product.

Comment: Thank you! can you please tell me about any other projections? In addition, in the case of orthogonal projections, is there any way to calculate the error? My best guess would be to calculate : $|| f(x,y) - Proj_f \rightarrow g ||$, where $|| y || = \sqrt{<y,y>}$